# flutter run not working gradle show exit code 1

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew, flutter-plugin

this is my error after running flutter run command it shows gradle debug running.
/C:/Users/Rasul/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/preload_page_view-0.1.6/lib/preload_page_view.dart:179:15: Error: The method
'PageMetrics.copyWith' doesn't have the named parameter 'devicePixelRatio' of overridden method 'Object with ScrollMetrics.copyWith'.
PageMetrics copyWith({
^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_metrics.dart:138:7: Context: This is the overridden method ('copyWith').
class FixedScrollMetrics with ScrollMetrics {
^
/C:/Users/Rasul/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/preload_page_view-0.1.6/lib/preload_page_view.dart:302:15: Error: The method
'_PagePosition.copyWith' doesn't have the named parameter 'devicePixelRatio' of overridden method 'ViewportOffset with ScrollMetrics.copyWith'.
PageMetrics copyWith({
^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:92:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('copyWith').
abstract class ScrollPosition extends ViewportOffset with ScrollMetrics {
^
/C:/Users/Rasul/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/preload_page_view-0.1.6/lib/preload_page_view.dart:170:13: Error: Required named parameter 'devicePixelRatio' must be provided.
}) : super(
^
/C:/Users/Rasul/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fluro-2.0.3/lib/src/fluro_router.dart:134:37: Error: The method 'copyWith' isn't defined for the class 'RouteSettings'.

- 'RouteSettings' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'copyWith'.
  settingsToUse = settingsToUse.copyWith(name: path);
  ^^^^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 22s.

flutter packages updated successfully with help of flutter pub upgrade.
i think everything is correctly pluged in but it shows this error again and again.

Comment: Is this by any chance a project that you cloned from a repository? If so, then there might be a version compatibility issue with the dependencies. If the repo's dependencies are not the newest, then they might conflict with your Flutter version.

Answer (score 0):

You've to follow some steps.

1. Run `flutter clean`
2. Restart your `VS Code/Android Studio`
3. After back to VS Code/Android Studio run - `flutter pub get`

> If your problem doesn't solve, check other projects running
> successfully or not.

**If successful** - try back up the necessary code(lib, yaml, etc) and replace with a new project.

**Otherwise,** - You need to upgrade gradle version in `android->build.gradle:dependencies`