# how to solve gradle java error in flutter run?

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/dynamicmethods/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/location-5.0.3/android/build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':location'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint'.
> Extension of type 'CommonExtension' does not exist. Currently registered extension types: [ExtraPropertiesExtension, BasePluginExtension, DefaultArtifactPublicationSet, SourceSetContainer, ReportingExtension, JavaToolchainService, JavaPluginExtension, NamedDomainObjectContainer, LibraryExtension, KotlinAndroidProjectExtension, KotlinTestsRegistry, KtlintExtension]

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/dynamicmethods/Documents/Manan_projects/flutter_projects/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 468
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':location'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

**PUBSPEC**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: any
  provider: any
  google_maps_flutter: any
  location: any
  geolocator: any
  google_maps_webservice: any
  pin_code_text_field: any
  shared_preferences: any
  sliding_up_panel: any
  carousel_slider: any
  connectivity: any
  flutter_spinkit: any
  geocoding: any
  google_maps: any
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

**ANDROID/BUILD.GRADLE**

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Comment: Hello, share your dependencies from `android/build.gradle`.

Comment: ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

Comment: try upgrading your version using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'`. Let me know it it works.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

Comment: Can you try this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76935184/12965265

Comment: already tried flutter clean and upgrade and also tried to upgrade build gradle