# this error i am getting after compiling flutter apk in android studio. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, android-studio

I am trying to generate a flutter apps signed apk from android studio but i am getting the error that the module was compiled with incomapatible version of kotlin.
this is my project level build.gradle file .

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

can someone know what i am doing wrong.
i am alo getting some -xlint deprecated by java errors which says recompile with xlint. but it does not show how to compile with x lint . can someone help me in solving this?

Comment: try upgrading the kotlin version

Comment: how can i  do this because i already update the kotlin version to 1.8.0?

Comment: Use the latest version of Kotlin available [ https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details ] and make sure to update the Kotlin version on Android Studio as well.

Check more possible solution here https://stackoverflow.com/q/67699823/12965265

Comment: ok i am trying it . now it shows this " The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0". this not solving my problem

Comment: Try this one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76935184/12965265

Comment: One thing you are missing is to upgrade flutter android app structure

Comment: how can i  do it because i dont update the structure before.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 7.3.0 seems to have some problem applying the correct kotlin_version. Try upgrade to Gradle 7.4.2. You can achieve that by opening the Android module in Android Studio. AS should ask you whether you want to upgrade your Gradle version. Then Proceed with the Gradle upgrade to 7.4.2, or whatever the latest version.