# problem when build gradle in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

When I build gradle in Android Studio, this error appears , An error also appears in the build.gradle

[erorr text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg8yM.png)

[erorr in build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agAKu.png)

I restarted and the problem is not fixed ,And I didn't find solutions to a problem like this

Comment: Can you try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76935184/12965265 ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this command:

```
./gradlew assemble -stacktrace
```

You might have 2 versions of Groovy on your classpath.
Take a look at it, correct your dependencies, if this is the problem, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

try
flutter clean
run `flutter doc` to check for an issue
and re run

else you might need to update your dependencies

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).